# How do you go about something like this? I assume you have to somehow go from the inverse to $x$ and $y$ but I need help making those steps.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $x, y \in G$. Show that $(xy)^{-1}\in G$

Comment: Use the group axioms and especially the closure property.

Comment: I think I get it thank you

Comment: I don't understand the question to be honest

Answer (score 2):

Because $xy\in G$ and $$(xy)^{-1}(xy)=e.$$

Also, easy to see that $$(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}.$$

Comment: I don't think this is what is being asked, Update: it is now after an edit from someone other than the OP.

Comment: @Jorge Fernández-Hidalgo  See the definition of a group. If $xy\in G$ so $(xy)^{-1}\in G$,

Comment: the original question said $xy^{-1}$, either way it's all good. I don't even understand why the question exists.

Comment: @Jorge Fernández-Hidalgo  It's also obvious, but I don't agree with you. See please better the history of the original post.

Comment: i mean it says xy^{-1} and then (xy inverse) and I guess xy inverse is (xy)^{-1} even though if you read it out loud it could be both either way. But once again, it's all good.

Comment: @Jorge Fernández-Hidalgo  I agree, it's a very strange question.